# Specify which directores to look for .htaccess file

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, apache-2.4, directory

I'd read that enabling .htaccess for all directories causes a performance overhead, because all subfolders are also scanned for .htaccess files.

I'd like to only have the .htaccess file read in:
/var/www/xgclan.com/public_html
and /var/www/xgclan.com/public_html/forum

I've configured the following in my apache2.conf (for /var/www/xgclan.com/public_html)

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/xgclan.com/public_html>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But this doesn't seem to work.. the sub directories are also read for .htaccess files

I should mention that xgclan.com is a virtualhost. 
What am I doing wrong?

I was able to prevent subdirectories from being checked for .htaccess files with:

```
<Directory /var/www/xgclan.com/public_html/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But this also blocked the .htaccess file in /var/www/xgclan.com/public_html/forum
So I tried adding the following rule to allow that specific directory:

```
<Directory /var/www/xgclan.com/public_html/forum>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the Directory section withing the VirtualHost declaration?

What is your error_log output when accessing the host on the browser? Do you get any error as stated [in the apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#troubleshoot)?

Ok, so if you want apache to scan just two specific folders out of the whole virtualhost directory for .htaccess files you should specify which ones you want to forbid and allow, something like:

```
<Directory /var/www/xgclan.com/public_html>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/xgclan.com/public_html/*/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/xgclan.com/public_html/forum>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: No, it works fine. but I've noticed that for example the .htaccess file in /var/www/xgclan.com/public_html/blabla

Is also being read, which it shouldn't..
I only want it to be read for: /var/www/xgclan.com/public_html

Comment: What is exactly what works fine? Sorry, I didn't get your comment :P

Comment: That the .htaccess files are being read. But I'd like to limit the folders in which Apache looks for the .htaccess file.

Comment: Ok, from your question I understood you wanted the .htaccess file to be read from _/var/www/xgclan.com/public_html _ and _/var/www/xgclan.com/public_html/forum_, the <Directory> directives (quote from [the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory)) _are used to enclose a group of directives that will apply only to the named directory, sub-directories of that directory, and the files within the respective directories_, so all subfolders of your directive will be scanned for .htaccess files. If you don't want that you could add another <Directory> for the subfolder.

Comment: You could also include whatever is on your .htaccess directly into the <Directory> directive on the virtualhost, avoiding the problems of performance on file access.

Comment: Edit answer to add an example that should work if I didn't misunderstand your requirements, but you can see there how to avoid "recursion" on the Directory directives.

Comment: I've used the code like you suggested, but the .htaccess file in the /forum directory is still ignored.

Comment: Sorry, edited again, the order of the directives is important as the last one which applies overwrites the previous ones, the one for _/var/www/xgclan.com/public_html/forum_ should be the last one.

Comment: Actually I had to make another one:

<Directory /var/www/xgclan.com/public_html/forum/*/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Which blocks the subfolders of the forum directory.